# Toggling page views in Skim

Tags: applescript, pdf, skim

When right-clicking on a document in `skim` there are two very useful options:

- Single Page (good for presentations)
- Single Page Continuous (suitable for reading)

Is there a way to define a shortcut which will toggle between the two? I guess `AppleScript` and probably [this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/skim-app/index.php?title=AppleScript#PDF_View_Settings) can be helpful. Problem is I don't know how to work with AppleScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just assigned custom shortcuts for the menu bar items.

[image]

You could also [assign a shortcut to an AppleScript](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this.

```
try
    tell application "Skim" to tell document 1
        if item -2 of (view settings as list) is single page then
            set view settings to {display mode:single page continuous}
        else
            set view settings to {display mode:single page}
        end if
    end tell
end try
```

Comment: Wow.  What an easy, great solution--the custom menu bar shortcut.  I didn't know about that.  I've wanted to map right-arrow and left-arrow to next page and previous page in Skim for years, and knew no way to do that.  The Skim developer was not sympathetic.   Your answer to this question, user49570, led me to the solution.  (I don't display all of the page, but don't need to move it left and right within the window.)